# How to convert a dollar fraction into a normal dollar amount

Tags: numerical-value

I'm trying to use Mathematica to compute compounded interest. I used Wolfram Alpha, and it gave me the code

```
FormulaData[{"PresentValueFutureValue", "Standard"},
    {"PV" -> Quantity[100000, "USDollars"], "i" -> Quantity[7, "Percent"], "n" -> 35}]
```

But when I type this in, I get a weird dollar fraction.

How do I turn this into a number that makes sense? I tried indexing into just the number part and doing the `// N` thing, like:

```
FormulaData[{"PresentValueFutureValue", "Standard"},
    {"PV" -> Quantity[100000, "USDollars"], "i" -> Quantity[7, "Percent"], "n" -> 35}][[1]][[2]] // N
```

but that just gives me a dollar sign.

What should I do to just get a normal dollar or decimal value?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeValue.html

Comment: change `Quantity[100000, "USDollars"]` to `QuantityMagnitude@Quantity[100000., "USDollars"]` or to `QuantityVariable[100000., "USDollars"]`?

Comment: Notice that you could just apply `N` to the result to have a simple decimal value: `FormulaData[....] // N` returns ``QuantityVariable["FV","Money"] == Quantity[1.1506151840662945`*^6, "USDollars"]``.